# What do the bytes and duration fields in squid log count for https (CONNECT)?

Tags: https, squid

Standard squid config only logs one CONNECT line for any https transaction.  What is being counted/timed by the reported bytes and duration fields in that line?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer via the squid-users mailing list [1]:

> Unless you are using SSL-Bump or such to process the contents specially.
>   The duration is from the CONNECT message arriving to the time TCP close
>   is used to end the tunnel. The size should be the bytes sent to the
>   client (excluding the 200 reply message itself) during that time.

[1] http://lists.squid-cache.org/pipermail/squid-users/2016-July/011714.html